# How to filterKeys of hashmap Not in given set

Tags: scala

Say I have two hashmaps

```
val currentMap = Map("current"-> 1)
val newMap = Map("current" -> 1, "new"->2)
```

Is there a way that I can obtain the "relative complement" of B in A i.e., newMap-currentMap?

New to scala - so sorry that these basic set operations are so complicated for me!

Comment: Sorry I found that doing val newMap.filterKeys( currentMap.contains(_) == false) works

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
newMap -- currentMap.keys
```